# Can I use Stripe API in my chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, stripe-payments

When running the test stripe card and API keys, the customer shows up in my backend. But switching to live credit card and keys, no customer shows up and I get this error.

> You are using Stripe.js in live mode over an insecure connection. This
>   is considered unsafe. Please conduct live requests only on sites
>   served over https. For more info, see https://stripe.com/help/ssl

Does anyone know how I can use Stripe in my chrome extension?

Comment: So, the error message clearly states what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a Stripe credit card form in Google Chrome extension-- unable to avoid "Payment not secure?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43329732/using-a-stripe-credit-card-form-in-google-chrome-extension-unable-to-avoid-pa)