# Is it possible to integrate Stripe into a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, angular6, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe but facing the following issues.

1. When I am loading normally via ngx-stripe, it's giving me this error in the console.

> Refused to load the script 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/' because it
>   violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src
>   'self' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly
>   set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

2. I change `content_security_policy` in manifest to `"script-src 'self' https://js.stripe.com/v3/; object-src 'self' "` but it's giving me this error in the console.

> Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because
>   'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
>   https://js.stripe.com/v3/".

3. After that, I tried adding `content_scripts` but it's giving me this error and don't let me to import the zip file as well while saying

> Could not load javascript '' for content script.

How can I overcome this issue? and is it possible to integrate Stripe into a chrome extension because Stripe only works via `https` but extension working with `chrome://`

Comment: I'd suggest checking out https://stackoverflow.com/a/43337625/100328

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @EndersJeesh works for me with Chrome extensions with manifest version 2.

I was wondering whether it was going to stop working in manifest version 3:

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#remotely-hosted-code

The Remotely Hosted Code says that you will not be able to load remote hosted code so I imagine that loading https://js.stripe.com/v3 will not be possible.

The best solution would be for all the Stripe code to be embedded in the extension but there's no npm package for this Stripe code.

Any comments from @EndersJeesh or others would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into these and several subsequent issues integrating stripe into a chrome extension.

**Explanation:**

I'll first state what I believe was happening. Using the stripe react libraries, I believe they have an inline js call somewhere, causing the error you're seeing about `js.stripe.com`. I think this would be fixed by adding `unsafe-inline` into your `content_security_policy`, but that will not be executed by chrome extensions per [the extension CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-inline-script).

**Solutions:**

So here are the various things I did (solving one typically led to having to solve the next set of errors).

1. I initially had my `constent_security_policy` set to

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://js.stripe.com/v3; object-src 'self';"
```

2. I was running into your issue above, and so I added the script into my header call, leading my `index.html` file to be the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3" async></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="modal-window"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

That resolved the first set of errors which matched yours above, but it led to the next set of issues:

3. I then hit a series of errors around `Refused to frame ... because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src"...`, so I fixed these by adding to my `content_security_policy` the following:

```
frame-src https://js.stripe.com/v3
```

So my final version of my `content_security_policy` is as follows:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://js.stripe.com/v3; object-src 'self'; frame-src https://js.stripe.com/v3"
```

I hope that does it for you. It took several hours to work through all of that for me.

Comment: works perfectly for manifest version 2. Will it stop working when manifest v3 comes out?

Comment: in manifest 3 you can't use any non self code so i guess it work with manifest 3